# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: mysql

Olá, estava criando uma tabela no `Postgres` e então a partir da linha onde escrevo
`ALTER TABLE FUNCIONARIO_USUARIO ADD CONSTRAINT adicona_FKCodCliente_FKCpfSup`
o código aparece o erro assim:

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for
> referenced table  "funcionario_usuario"

Alguém poderia me explicar qual é o erro?

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE (
CodCliente VARCHAR UNIQUE,
FK_PESSOA_Cpf VARCHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (CodCliente));

CREATE TABLE PRODUTO (
Modelo VARCHAR,
Genero VARCHAR,
Cor VARCHAR,
Preco DOUBLE PRECISION,
Fabricante VARCHAR,
Tamanho INTEGER,
CodigoProd VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
FK_NumVenda VARCHAR);

CREATE TABLE FUNCIONARIO_USUARIO (
Salario DOUBLE PRECISION,
CodFuncionario VARCHAR,
DataContratacao DATE,
Cargo VARCHAR,
FK_CpfFuc VARCHAR,
FK_CodSupervisor VARCHAR,
FK_CpfSupervisor VARCHAR,
Senha VARCHAR,
Nome_user VARCHAR,
PRIMARY KEY (CodFuncionario, FK_CpfFuc, Nome_user),
UNIQUE (CodFuncionario, FK_CpfFuc, Nome_user));

CREATE TABLE VENDA (
Valor DOUBLE PRECISION,
Data DATE,
Forma_pg VARCHAR,
Hora TIME,
Num_venda VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
FK_ClienteCod VARCHAR,
FK_ClienteCpf VARCHAR,
FK_FuncCod VARCHAR,
FK_FuncCpf VARCHAR);

CREATE TABLE PESSOA (
Sexo VARCHAR,
NomeCompleto VARCHAR,
Cpf VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
Telefone VARCHAR,
DataNasc DATE,
Endereco VARCHAR);

ALTER TABLE CLIENTE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENTE_2
FOREIGN KEY (FK_PESSOA_Cpf)
REFERENCES PESSOA (Cpf)
ON DELETE CASCADE;


ALTER TABLE PRODUTO ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUTO_2
FOREIGN KEY (FK_NumVenda)
REFERENCES VENDA (Num_venda)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE FUNCIONARIO_USUARIO ADD CONSTRAINT adiciona_FK_CpfFunc
FOREIGN KEY (FK_CpfFuc)
REFERENCES PESSOA (Cpf)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE FUNCIONARIO_USUARIO ADD CONSTRAINT adicona_FKCodCliente_FKCpfSup
FOREIGN KEY (FK_CodSupervisor, FK_CpfSupervisor)
REFERENCES FUNCIONARIO_USUARIO (CodFuncionario, FK_CpfFuc);

ALTER TABLE VENDA ADD CONSTRAINT adiciona_FKClientCod_FKFuncCpf
FOREIGN KEY (FK_ClienteCod, FK_ClienteCpf)
REFERENCES CLIENTE (CodCliente, FK_PESSOA_Cpf)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE VENDA ADD CONSTRAINT adiciona_FKFuncCod_FKFuncCpf
FOREIGN KEY (FK_FuncCod, FK_FuncCpf)
REFERENCES FUNCIONARIO_USUARIO (CodFuncionario, FK_CpfFuc)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: A pk da tabela FUNCIONARIO_USUARIO é  (CodFuncionario, FK_CpfFuc, Nome_user) foi referenciado (FK_CodSupervisor, FK_CpfSupervisor) , sem entrar no mérito do modelo em si.

Comment: pra além do que o @Motta comentou, colunas `VARCHAR` devem especificar o tamanho

Comment: Achei estranho também (varchar) mas como não trabalho com MySql achei que ele tratasse de alguma forma ....